# Damage player when touching water terrain

Tags: roblox

I'm trying to decrease a player's health when they touch some water terrain in ROBLOX.
I'm not sure why this doesn't work, but it doesn't. If someone could help me out that would be neat.

```
while wait() do
    local player = game.Workspace.LocalPlayer
    local headLoc = game.Workspace.Terrain:WorldToCell(player.Character.Head.Position)
    local hasAnyWater = game.Workspace.Terrain:GetWaterCell(headLoc.x, headLoc.y, headLoc.z)
    if player.Character.Humanoid.Health ~= 0 then
        if hasAnyWater then
            player.Character.Humanoid:TakeDamage(0.2)
        end
    end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you check your output window you'll see why:

```
LocalPlayer is not a valid member of Workspace
```

LocalPlayer is in "Players", so you should declare:

```
local player = game.Players.LocalPlayer
```

So if you change that, and have it in a LocalScript for example in the StarterPlayerScripts folder, everything works just like you want.

Comment: Yeah. I've noticed and corrected it. Thanks anyways though mate.

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

```
local player = game:GetService("Players").LocalPlayer
while wait(0.5) do
local headLoc = game.Workspace.Terrain:WorldToCell(player.Character.LowerTorso.Position) or game.Workspace.Terrain:WorldToCell(player.Character.Torso.Position)
local hasAnyWater = game.Workspace.Terrain:GetWaterCell(headLoc.x, headLoc.y, headLoc.z)
if player.Character.Humanoid.Health ~= 0 then
    if hasAnyWater then
            player.Character.Humanoid:TakeDamage(8)
        end
    end
end
```